# Entity Framework not recognizing Custom Identity Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I've set up an ApplicationUser type like this:

```
public class BusinessAccount : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string RepFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string RepLastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<BusinessAccount> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

I also have this DbContext:

```
public class AleHubDbContext :IdentityDbContext<BusinessAccount>
    {
        public AleHubDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }

        public static AleHubDbContext Create()
        {
            return new AleHubDbContext();
        }

    }
```

Both are in the same namespace. However, when I run a migration, none of the above-defined custom properties are appearing. The system just scaffolds up a plain-old IdentityUser style table structure with just the boilerplate. It's as if EF doesn't even "see" my BusinessAccount entity. Is there any other connection that could be causing the problem? Thanks.

Versions:

```
Id                                  Versions                                 ProjectName                                                                        
--                                  --------                                 -----------                                                                        
EntityFramework                     {6.1.3}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core      {2.2.1}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Entity... {2.2.1}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin      {2.2.1}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi             {5.2.3}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client      {5.2.3}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core        {5.2.3}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin        {5.2.3}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelf... {5.2.3}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost     {5.2.3}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotN... {1.0.0}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.Net.Compilers             {1.0.0}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.Owin                      {3.0.1}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener    {2.0.2}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.Owin.Hosting              {2.0.2}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.Owin.Security             {3.0.1}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies     {3.0.1}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth       {3.0.1}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Newtonsoft.Json                     {6.0.4}                                  AleHub.API                                                                         
Owin                                {1.0}                                    AleHub.API                                                                         
Antlr                               {3.4.1.9004}
```

**Initial Migration.... No custom props in sight!**
 public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetRoles",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
            c => new
                {
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId)
            .Index(t => t.RoleId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUsers",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                    EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    PasswordHash = c.String(),
                    SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                    PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                    LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                    AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserClaims",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ClaimType = c.String(),
                    ClaimValue = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AspNetUserLogins",
            c => new
                {
                    LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", "UserId", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", "RoleId", "dbo.AspNetRoles");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserLogins", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserClaims", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUsers", "UserNameIndex");
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "RoleId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetUserRoles", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.AspNetRoles", "RoleNameIndex");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
        DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you implement the UserStore too?

Comment: @MaximilianoRios according to this tutorial: http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/ that step is not needed to create the properties in the DB. Notice he does not implement UserStore until after. And I also tried to implement it and it does not solve the problem :\

Comment: I do understand, it's simply I don't see (usually) an implementation that doesn't add UserStore. Anyways, can you indicate what's the version of IF you're using? Framework, IF, etc. so I can take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you. Im not sure what you mean by IF but I just updated the post with the versions.

Comment: The migration gets the T type from IdentityDbContext<T> to build the object. Just to confirm it I created a migration and it worked perfectly adding your objects. Can you post your CreateTable code from the InitialCreate class? Mine worked perfectly

Comment: CreateTable(
                "dbo.AspNetUsers",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                        RepFirstName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                        RepLastName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                        Title....

Comment: I see everything there, no errors.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios

Really? That makes NO sense. Did your DB have the actual custom properties?? Check out my InitialCreate above. Thanks so much for working with me, this is bizarre.

Comment: Yes, it does contain all the objects. This is a workaround but just to confirm, have you tried to add manually the elements and see if they are pulled from the database? There must be some reference somewhere to the IUser that makes it build the script with the base interface. I have slightly different versions but I don't think there should be a problem.

Comment: Try to fallback to the EXACT versions the sample project was created with and rerun the migration.

Comment: I'm really curious about this issue, it's very particular and I didn't see it failing before. Are you still working on that?